# Query DynamoDB by List<Ids> of Global Secondary Index

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a GSI setup on my personId field:

`@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "personId", globalSecondaryIndexName = "personIndex")`

`private UUID personId;`

Now the use case is where I will get a request containing `List<UUID> personsIds` and I need to query the DDB and get the results.

One option that I know is that I will have to call dynamoDB one by one to get the results.

Is there a way where this can be done in a single call (a batch request may be) ? Though I am not sure if that is possible using GSI.

Would appreciate any help in this.

Thanks.

Comment: BatchGetItem only works with primary keys. You likely need to scan with an IN filter expression or issue N queries.

Comment: The `TableKeysAndAttributes` class accepts both Hash and Range keys with  for Primary Indices, but the source has no mention of GSIs.  See [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/TableKeysAndAttributes.html) and [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html#JavaDocumentAPIGetItem)